# Printing wrong index values in mergesort recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, output, mergesort

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int* arr, int l, int mid, int r)
{
    int n1=mid-l+1;
    int n2=r-mid;
    int L[n1],R[n2];
    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++)
        L[i]=arr[l+i];
    for(int i=0; i<n2; i++)
        R[i]=arr[mid+1+i];
    int i=0,j=0,k=l;
    while(i<n1 && j<n2){
        if(L[i]<=R[j])
            arr[k++]=L[i++];
        else
            arr[k++]=R[j++];
    }
    while(i<n1)
        arr[k++]=L[i++];
    while(j<n2)
        arr[k++]=R[j++];
}

void mergesort(int* arr, int l, int r)
{
    if(l<r){
        int mid=(l+r)/2;
        printf("MS(%d, %d)\n", l,r);
        mergesort(arr, l, mid);
        printf("MS(%d, %d)\n", l,r);
        mergesort(arr, mid+1, r);
        printf("MS(%d, %d)\n", l,r);
        merge(arr, l, mid, r);
        printf("Afte Merge:    MS(%d, %d)\n", l,r);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {5, 2, 1, 6, 7, 9, 4};
    mergesort(arr, 0, 6);
    for(auto x:arr)
        cout<<x<<' ';

    return 0;

}
```

I am printing the values of l and r to check their values at each recursive call. But it is not comming quite correct. One example after the first time merge is called is :-

```
OUTPUT:
MS(0, 6)
MS(0, 3)
MS(0, 1)
MS(0, 1)
MS(0, 1)
Afte Merge:    MS(0, 1)
```

Here line 4 and 5(starting from 1 as MS(0, 6)) should print MS(0,0) and MS(1,1) respectively. Please tell What am I doing wrong I want the correct output.
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As l == r so MS(0,0) can't be printed.

if you use if(l <= r) then there will be an infinite loop.

So, your code is accurate.

```
if(l<r){
        int mid= l + (r-l)/2;
        printf("MS(%d, %d)\n", l,r);
        mergesort(arr, l, mid);
        printf("MS(%d, %d)\n", l,r);
        mergesort(arr, mid+1, r);
        printf("MS(%d, %d)\n", l,r);
        merge(arr, l, mid, r);
        printf("Afte Merge:    MS(%d, %d)\n", l,r);
    }
```

Comment: Right, didn't noticed just have to paste a print statement before if() now i can print when l==r  , Thank You!